# Summary of row values according to summation of n number

Tags: sql

I have table like this

```
a | b
_____
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 4
5 | 5
```

and i want the result like this

```
a | b | c
_________
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 3
3 | 3 | 6
4 | 4 | 10
5 | 5 | 15
```

Comment: Which is your database? MS Sql server, Oracle, MySql etc...

Comment: example for MS SQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbbfd/3